# I deployed my project, I am getting this error Input file contains unsupported image format

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, github-actions

I am trying to build in my production environment (i using GitHub actions to do the deploy), but the wrong is what the node is not the same between in my local

in my local i have this version:

```
npm -v
-> 7.24.1

node -v
-> v14.13.1
```

but I don't know what is the node version on GitHub actions
I **can not reproduce the error in my local**, because the version are not the same

I am getting this error:

```
success extract queries from components - 4.464s
success write out redirect data - 0.001s
success Build manifest and related icons - 0.003s
error "gatsby-plugin-manifest" threw an error while running the onPostBootstrap lifecycle:

Input file contains unsupported image format


  Error:Input file contains unsupported image format

not finished onPostBootstrap - 0.025s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

and these are my dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.11.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^7.15.4",
    "gatsby": "^2.22.15",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.12.87",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-redux": "1.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.6.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "3.3.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.8",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "2.5.3",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "3.3.0",
    "npm": "^7.5.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "stopword": "^1.0.3",
    "tracking-number-validation": "^2.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
}
```

this is the build.yml to deploy to production

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ github.ref }}
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i dont know what is the node version on github actions i can not reproduce the error in my local, because of the version are not the same

You could use `setup-node` action to make the version exactly same with your local:

```
- uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: '14.13.1'
- run: npm install -g npm@7.24.1
- run: npm -v
- run: node -v
```

The output in github:

```
Run npm -v
  npm -v
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
7.24.1
Run node -v
  node -v
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
v14.13.1
```

Comment: but how can I find out the github node to install it on my local

Comment: Same, just not force install any new node in github action, add `run: node -v`, then in github you could see the log output to see which version of node it used.

Comment: should that put it in the build file? i added that file in my question, please see, in what part should i put run: node -v, i dont want to break please

Comment: After `steps:`, it's same as your other step. You already make some `run` in your yaml like `run: npm install`, copy that.

Comment: i am going to put like this:  steps:
      - name: version node
         run: node -v.       its ok?

Comment: YES.... go on please.